# Moving Java EE Project to a Linux Server

Tags: linux, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, war

I've never worked with Java EE before. I'm trying to learn both Java EE and linux environment.

I wrote a really simple web server and using tomcat to serve it. Everything works perfectly on my Windows machine. I'm trying to run the server on a linux machine.

I created a .war file using maven and I'm pulling that file from git to the linux machine.

The problem starts here.. when I put that file to tomcat7/webapps it only shows me the front-end but back-end doesn't work (get requests return nothing). So I figured I need to run the server separately. I'm trying to use "java -cp war_file.war test.getSomething" but it says "Error: Could not find or load main class test.getSomething"

Apparently I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure that out. I appreciate any help, Thanks!

Comment: Which one was the first backend error?

Comment: "Could not find or loand main class ..." is a basic java error. Did you try googling for it? Good luck.

Comment: You are trying to achieve "much" with little knowledge. Try a step back and go to basics. Your approach seems to introduce many smells, like pulling a war from a remote git repository.

Also, try using WildFly or any other mature application server instead of Tomcat. They can provide better troubleshooting options for newbies (offer a decent GUI). However, if your application is Spring application, you may have troubles with deployment to anything else than Tomcat.